# Is there any method to Scrollto exact keyword and exact if it was not visible in current window, I am using wd npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, appium, appium-android, appium-desktop

**I have a problem in scrolling in appium javascript. I want to move to the exact text and id which is not visible in the current window on the mobile screen.I am using wd npm**

I have a problem in scrolling in appium javascript.I am using wd npm. I want to move to the exact text and id which is not visible in the current window on the mobile screen. Its existence in the center of the screen.When i use driver.scrolltoExact('text') , this method is not implemented, driver.scroll(10,200) also not working. For this, I used now touch action in javascript inside a while(true), Now the problem is this, it does not scroll fix axis, it scrolls sometimes to the end and sometimes not scroll and sometimes scroll according to the axis. I want to scroll fix axis of y.

```
  while (true) {
          await delay(1000);
          i = i + 1;
          try {
            let classname = await driver.elementsByClassName(
              "android.view.View"
            );
            for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
              let a = await classname[i].text();
              array.push(a);
              if (a == "Share") {
                await delay(3000);
                await classname[i].click();
                break;
              }
            }
          } catch (error) {
            await new wd.TouchAction(driver)
              .press({ x: 65, y: 780 })
              .moveTo({ x: 65, y: 155 })
              .release()
              .perform();
            if (i > 5) {
              break;
            }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

From your example, it looks like you are trying to do in Android platform. You can give a try with this

**driver.findElements(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains(\"" + textToSearch + "\").instance(0))")).size() > 0**

// break/return

Comment: what is MobileBy?

Comment: You can add dependency for io.appium.java_client in your project to use MobileBy Ref: https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/MobileBy.html